# Is it safe to pass data from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, security, authentication, web

I save my logged in ID in the PHP session of course.
Is it safe and professional to pass the id from PHP to JavaScript in my sorce code as following :

```
var myLoggedInId = "<?php echo $theLoggedInIdFromSession; ?>";
```

Comment: Any data that you expose on a website is public, thus, insecure.

Comment: myLoggedInId  is user name?

Comment: No the loggedInId is not the user name.
This user id is not something secret. is it ok for the public to know.
I'm talking about the method of passing data through php to js in general.

Comment: I'm not php coder, so I don't know if it's professional or not. But I've seen alot of code that indeed uses <?php ?> tag to dynamically create functions  /variables for clientside on the server.

Comment: Why communicate the user-ID and not rely on the session-ID? It is a randomly generated string, in contrast to user-IDs, which are usually numeric and generated (pseudo-)sequentially (therefore to access data of another user you increase or decrease the id until you find data of another account).

Answer (score 0):

JS code is client side, this means that any user can debug it using the developer tools in any browser and get the value of any desired variables. So no its not save.

Comment: But can they change it also?
Viewing the user id is fine with me, but can they change this data?

Comment: Yes they can, using the console while debugging the JS using their browser

Comment: You mustn't let people to send sensitive data by javascript because it could be changed. But why you ask this? This data sends from server to client not from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal thing in asp and php snding data to javascript. And what you send to javascript is not different (in security) to other public data. So if the user name is public there is no problem to send this to javascript.

Comment: Yes but can they change the value in the js code? if so they can change it to othe user ids and view the system as they are logged in from someone else.

Comment: Yes they can change it but if you write your code truly they can not do any harmful thing to you site.

Comment: The thing is important is the user name you send to js must be only for reading. and no method in server that get sensitive data from js codes.